# How to load a PMML model?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, pmml

I'm following the instructions of [PMML model export - spark.mllib](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/mllib-pmml-model-export.html#examples) to create a K-means model.

```
val numClusters = 10
val numIterations = 10
val clusters = KMeans.train(data, numClusters, numIterations)
// Save and load model: export to PMML
println("PMML Model:\n" + clusters.toPMML("/kmeans.xml"))
```

But I don't know how to load the PMML after that.

I'm trying

```
val sameModel = KMeansModel.load(sc, "/kmeans.xml")
```

and appears:

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/kmeans.xml/metadata
```

Any idea?

Best regards

Comment: Seems like there aren't any method to import a PMML model. So, I changed the way to create the model, with `KMeansModel.save`

Comment: Is it important to store the model in PMML format only? Because you can just save the model and then reload it.

Comment: I would recommend you look at this project, which adds more fully-featured PMML-functionality to Spark: https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-spark.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the documentation (for the version you seem to be interested it - 1.6.1 and also for the latest available - 2.1.0) Spark supports *exporting* to PMML only. The `load` method actually expects to retrieve a model saved in Spark own format and this is why the `load` method expects a certain path to be there and why the exception has been thrown.

If you trained the model with Spark, you can `save` it and `load` it later.

If you need to load a model that has not been trained in Spark and has been saved as PMML you can use [jpmml-spark](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-spark) to load and evaluate it.

Answer (score 1):

My limited experience in this spark.mllib's KMeans space is that it is not possible, but you *could* develop the feature yourself.

spark.mllib's `KMeansModel` [is](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/clustering/KMeansModel.scala#L39-L40) `PMMLExportable`:

```
class KMeansModel @Since("1.1.0") (@Since("1.0.0") val clusterCenters: Array[Vector])
  extends Saveable with Serializable with PMMLExportable {
```

That's why you can use [toPMML](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/pmml/PMMLExportable.scala#L76) that saves a model into the PMML XML format.

(Again I've got a very little experience in Spark MLlib) My understanding is that KMeans is all about centroids and that's what is loaded when you do [KMeansModel.load](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/clustering/KMeansModel.scala#L104-L106) that in turn uses [KMeansModel.SaveLoadV1_0.load](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/clustering/KMeansModel.scala#L135-L147) that reads the centroids and creates a `KMeansModel`:

```
new KMeansModel(localCentroids.sortBy(_.id).map(_.point))
```

For `KMeansModel.toPMML`, Spark MLlib uses pmml-model's `PMML` (as you can see [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/pmml/export/PMMLModelExport.scala#L41)):

```
new PMML("4.2", header, null)
```

I'd recommend exploring pmml-model's `PMML` how to do saving and loading as that's beyond Spark's realm.

---

### Side notes

Why would you even want to use Spark to have the model after you trained it? It is indeed possible, but you may be wasting your cluster resources for Spark to host the model.

In my limited understanding, the sole purpose of Spark MLlib is to use Spark's features like distribution and parallelism to handle large datasets to build models and use them without the Spark machinery afterwards.

*I must be missing something important in my narrow view...*

Comment: Hi Jacek, I was using that to a Near Real Time analysis. So I used the Lambda Architecture: I made a batch model (that need a lot of time) and we I needed to analysed the data I wanted to load that model.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [PMML4S-Spark](https://github.com/autodeployai/pmml4s-spark) to load a PMML model to evaluate it in Spark, for example:

```scala
import org.pmml4s.spark.ScoreModel

val model = ScoreModel.fromFile("/kmeans.xml")
```

The `model` is a SparkML transformer, so you can make prediction against a dataframe:

```scala
val scoreDf = model.transform(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

PMML files are actually xml files with schemas defined by Data Mining Consortium. For that reason you can either define a deserializer based on the contract given at DMC and PMML web page here or use 3rd party libraries.

I am researching on **jpmml** library for incorporation python prepared models in Spring application.

Information here:
https://github.com/jpmml
http://dmg.org/pmml/v4-1/GeneralStructure.html